# How to add rel="nofollow" to wp_list_pages?

Tags: navigation, pages, nofollow

I'd like to use the wp_list_pages as a navigation bar, but I don't want the links to be followed. This is the simple version of the code I'm using `<?php wp_list_pages('hierarchical=1&title_li=&depth=1'); ?>` but I have no idea how to add the "nofollow" to the links.

Answer (score 3):

use wordpress build in funcion for that "wp_rel_nofollow"
with a hook to wp_list_pages.

paste this code in your theme's functions.php file and you are set.

```
function add_no_follow($output){
  return wp_rel_nofollow($output);
}
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'add_no_follow');
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I think this will nofollow all wp_list_pages links on my site. I'm using this code for different purposes (to list different groups of pages) and I don't want all of them no-followed, just the links in my nav-bar.

Comment: @Zmey: You can disable `echo` for `wp_list_pages()`, give the output to `wp_rel_nofollow()`, and echo the result of that.

Comment: @Zmey - If you've found a solution with the information provided, please be sure to mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

paste this code in your theme's functions.php file.

```
function add_nofollow($text) {
    return str_replace('<a href=', '<a rel="nofollow" href=',  $text);    
}

add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'add_nofollow');
```